# Edittext not editable after dragged

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-edittext

I have added drag functinality to my custom editext by overriding the  touchevent()

Now the problem is after the edittext is dragged and dropped in a particular position and i want to input text into the edittext by clicking on it, it still getting dragged maybe because the touch event has been overriden and keyboard does not appear to input text

The workaround maybe triggering the dragfunctionality on long press but now the default longpress functionality of the edittext may change

I dont want this to happen

What to do.

**mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   
RelativeLayout dropLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    dropLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ondraglayout);  
    dropLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mainEditText1);


}   

}
```

**my customedittext.java**

```
public class CustomEdittext extends EditText
{
public CustomEdittext(Context context){
    super(context);

}

public CustomEdittext(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
    super(context, attr);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

             break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            ClipData dragdata = ClipData.newPlainText("","");

            View.DragShadowBuilder shdwbldr = new View.DragShadowBuilder(this);

            this.startDrag(dragdata, shdwbldr, this, 0);
            this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

**mydraglistener.java**

```
public class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener
{

private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
{
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();


    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();  
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
            x=  (int) event.getX();
            y =  (int) event.getY();
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();
            params.leftMargin = x;
            params.topMargin = y;

            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            break;
        default: break;
    }
    return true;
}


}
```

**my main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#CDC2C0"
android:id="@+id/ondraglayout">

<com.mycompany.myapp.CustomEdittext
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainEditText1"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried to cast the dragged `View` to your `CustomEditText` when dropped? (  `view = (CustomEditText) view;` or something like that)

Comment: @Amylinn nope,,,nothing ,,,the code that i have posted is all what i did

Comment: ... Then.. um.. try it? To make this safer, you could wrap it in a condition checking with `view instanceof CustomEditText`.

Comment: @Amylinn ya even tried it also but dint make any difference

Comment: Try to only return `true` for the `onMove`, but not for the `onTouch` in the touchlistener

Comment: @Amylinn the best way i round was to trigger the drag function by setting onlongclicklistener to the custom eduttext but i loose the functionality of copy and paste to the custom edittext,,,

Comment: @Amylinn ya i ll try and let you know

Comment: @Amylinn tried as you said but even 4he drag functinality is also gone along with text input

Comment: So, for clarity. if you return `true` in the touchlistener, you tell android you handle the clicks on the view by yourself. What you may do is to create a workaround, by measuring the pressed time - lower than 0.3 secs -> simple touch, request focus. lower than 0.5 -> onpress, open copy&paste, even longer: this should be a drag. Maybe dive into the Actions documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)

Comment: @Amylinn wow,,great workaround but how can you measure the pressed rime

Comment: Just save it in a class-global `long pressStarted` and compare it to the time in `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_MOVE`. But this behaviour may be unexpected for the user. I think you'll need to dive through the documentations to get the correct times.. :)

Comment: @Amylinn the idea looks good but the time gap replicates as of the same like longpreesed only??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114017/discussion-between-amylinn-and-user5894647).

Comment: @Amylinn r u on chat??

Answer (score 1):

Your whole code not making sense at all: First let discuss what happening inside your `onTouchEvent`:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
 {
    switch(event.getAction()){
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :

         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        ClipData dragdata = ClipData.newPlainText("","");

        View.DragShadowBuilder shdwbldr = new View.DragShadowBuilder(this);

        this.startDrag(dragdata, shdwbldr, this, 0);
        this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
}
return true;
```

When you put your finger in the screen, the system first trigger `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, and afterwards, she will deliver events of `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` as long as nothing else in the system will consume this events. The meaning of this is your call for `startDrag()` will call on each movement of the finger, not really make sense right? So first I suggest you to move the code from `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` into `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

Now to the more important part. When you assign a `DragListener` to `View`, the meaning is that this `View` will receive all the `DragEvent` that the system will deliver as long as the `Listener` returns `true` for the `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED`.

Now, you assigned your `DragListener`, to the `RelativeLayout`. So lets look into your code:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        params.leftMargin = x;
        params.topMargin = y;

        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        break;
```

You set new position for the `LayoutParams`, but who is the `View` that will receive this params? The `RelativeLayout`, not your `EditText`.  Actually your `EditText` is now `INVISBLE` as you set it visibilty to `INVISIBLE` inside your `onTouchEvent` and never changed it back. Your code "`view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`" inside the `ACTION_DROP` is not referring to the `EditText` but to the `RelativeLayout`. Unless there is other code you not shown here, this is the case.

Anyway, in your case I would recommend you to move your `startDrag()` call to a `LongCLickListener`. I have no clue which functionality of the `EditText` you think that may change ,as, at least as far as I know, there is no functionality for `LongClick` in `EditText`. If you want to avoid it you can also add a flag to your code and turn it on after the `ACTION_DROP`, and then  make the code inside the `ACTION_DOWN` to run just if this flag is set to false.

Comment: Thank you for taking out so much time and putting out the explanation in the best way possible. Really loved the explanation. As you said to assign the drag and drop code to longclicklistener will it not override the functionality of selecting ,copy,pasting of the edit text,,,,,,and I used View view=(View) event.getLocalState             in ondrag()   so that I can refer to the edit text and set it layoutparams(is this wrong)

Comment: Yes, you have access to the `EditText` and change it params and visibility when you call  `event.getLocalState() `, there is nothing wrong about it.

I don't think that the functionality of copy and paste text will change if you will move your code to LongClick listener, but you can try, and if this is the case you can try my second suggestion. You can also disable the listener in any point you want by calling `setOnLongClickListener(null)`

Comment: ya I will try setting the drag and drop block to onlongclicklistener and let you know,,,,thank you